# Fermat's Number Theorem: $F_n | (F_{m}-2)$ for all $m>n$

Tags: number-theory

Is there any way to show that $F_n | (F_{m}-2)$ for all $m>n$ apart from try and error fixing in numbers.

Comment: Let m= n+1. Does $F_n$ divide $F_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: The correct statement is $F_n\mid(F_m-2)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Agreed. Problem will be from where i copied question from.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio NO. equation resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $F_n = 2^{2^n}+1$, given $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$ we also have
$$ F_m-2=2^{2^m}-1=\left(2^{2^{m-1}}-1\right)\left(2^{2^{m-1}}+1\right)$$
and by induction
$$ F_m-2 = \prod_{n=0}^{m-1} F_n. $$

Comment: @bujufrancis: such claim is false. $F_n$ is a divisor of $F_m-2$, not a divisor of $F_{m-2}$. Does it look to you that $3$ is a divisor of $17$, or a divisor of $257$?

Comment: Agreed. Problem from original source of question

Answer (score 0):

$$F_{k+1}-1=2^{2^{k+1}}=(2^{2^k})^2=(F_k-1)^2$$
and so $F_{k+1}=1+(F_k-1)^2$.
So $F_{n+1}\equiv1+(-1)^2\equiv2\pmod{F_n}$, $F_{n+2}\equiv1+(2-1)^2\equiv2\pmod{F_n}$ etc., and we see that induction will give $F_{n+k}\equiv2\pmod{F_n}$ for all $k\ge1$.